# User creation and group assignment succeeds but with error in the log file

Tags: batch-file

Following script is used to create user in windows and assign him remote user group.

I have redirected the output of STDOUT and STDERR in seperate files.

The script runs fine and creates user and adds user to the group. and same can be seen in the STDOUT file

But,

along with that I get following error in the STDERR File as follows:

account already exist and user is already group member of "Remote Desktop Users"

```
:Logit
echo %date% %time%

echo Creating user %USERLOGIN%
net user %USERLOGIN% /add

echo Adding user %USERLOGIN% to group "Remote Desktop Users"
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" %USERLOGIN% /add
```

Comment: Unfortunate... What is the question?

Comment: maybe the user account already exists or the user is already a member of the remote desktop users. You could check to see if the user account already exists or if the user is already a group member of Remote Desktop Users.

Comment: @WimOmbelets No I checked that and the user is not there I tried with couple of users and still same result

Comment: what does `net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" | findstr %USERLOGIN%` tell you?